# Checking email-id to whom jira issue is assigned to

Tags: python, jira

I have a python flask api that takes some input from and verify those details with jira.

I was fetching email-id of the user to whom the jira ticket is assigned to, with

```
issue = jira.issue(ticket)

assignee_email = issue.raw['fields']['assignee']['emailAddress']
```

it is working fine about 15-20days ago but now Jira is not sending email address.

I want to get the email-id of the user.

Thanks in advance.